# Non-Latin characters in URL (Google App Engine)

Tags: google-app-engine, url, non-latin

In my project I have html file with non-Latin characters: Кондиционер.html. When i make request:
www.myDomain.com/Кондиционер.html

Server sends 404 error:

**Error: Not Found
The requested URL /%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80.html was not found on this server.**

But with Latin latters everything works fine.
What can I do to set GAE server to support such non-Latin file names?

Comment: And is this in production, or the SDK, or both?

Comment: Project is developed in Eclipse, GWT + embedded App engine SDK. I created html file in the WAR directory. I think it must be static by default: http://code.google.com/intl/en/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/staticfiles.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this (does not work on the web-console, but in real *.py files):

```
print urllib.unquote("Ober%C3%B6sterreich.txt").decode("utf8")
```

For static files you need a redirecting request handler and an ascii-named file to which you redirect.