# Google App Engine non-latin names for files&folders?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, utf-8

I need to have cyrillic file and folder names. Example `/запись/Index.html` But i'm getting error when accessing these files. It says that GAE couldn't find them. I really think it is because encoding. But doesn't GAE support UTF8?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Non-Latin characters in URL (Google App Engine)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068842/non-latin-characters-in-url-google-app-engine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different operating systems store filenames in different ways. In Linux, filenames are uninterpreted byte strings, while in Windows they are unicode strings. This means that cross-platform compatibility with unicode filenames are tough.

The easiest way around this is to stick to names that are representable in both - eg, the lower 128 codepoints. You don't *need* cyrillic filenames, because the filenames are an internal detail of your app. You can serve any file you want under any URL path you want, independent of where it's stored, or if it's dynamic or static.